# Extending the 16-bit value to the 32-bit form in Assembly and questions about U2 code

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

Recently I asked a question here but it wasn't asked properly. I've read a lot but I still don't fully understand some things, but from the beginning:
I received program code written in Assembly (.COM). Adds two whole numbers together. Both numbers must be in the range [-32768..32767]. Both of these numbers must be converted from character to 16-bit form in U2 code. However, the result of this addition must be 32-bit, also in U2 (using 32-bit registers). 
This code has almost 150 lines so maybe I will only include pieces of this code. I must understand each line fairly well. I can describe most of them but still don't fully understand certain lines. (lines that I don't understand are in bold)

Firstly:

```
         .386p          
         .MODEL TINY
      
    
 Code       SEGMENT USE16           
                            ORG 100h
.
Sign            db      0
.
    
 Start: 
                     **mov      byte ptr [Sign], 0**    ;Do I understand correctly that we set the high bit to 0 here? As positive by default 
                      xor       ax, ax                           
                      push      ax  

                         ;here (Adding: ) I understand everything, addition of 2 numbers is done and some conditions 
Adding:             
                     pop        ax          ;second number          
                     pop        bx          ;first number           
                     add        ax, bx      ;adding         
                            
                     jo     Overflow_Flag           
                     js     Sign_Flag           
                     jmp    On_ASCII    ;convert to ASCII
                
                But I don't understand this following thing. When the result of this addition is negative, we "jump" to the Sing_Flag label and ...
Sign_Flag :
                  **mov     ebx, 0ffff0000h**       ;Why are we writing mov ebx, 0ffff0000h here? 
                    add     ebx, eax                ;further I understand 
                    neg     ebx                     
                            
                    mov     dl, '-'         

    
                mov     ah, 02h                 
                int     21h                     
            
                mov     eax,ebx                 
                jmp     On_ASCII
```

I would like to present how I understand it: 
FFFF0000h = 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 
With this line we extend the 16-bit value to the 32-bit form.
For example, the result of this addition is: -5, so: 
5 = 0101 (BIN) 
NEG(0101) + 1 = 1010 + 1 = 1011 = -5 (DEC) 
So in this case:
0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 111 1011  (neg ebx) 
And that's what I don't understand/couldn't find information:

1. Why 0ffff0000h and not e.g. 000000000h? What are these four 1s for?
2. How does the Assembler know where the "end" of a number is? We have 1111 1111 1111 1011 and why doesn't it count the next 1?
3. Do I understand mov byte ptr [Sign], 0? 
   Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first bold line initializes the variable `Sign` to zero. It is not used anymore in the scrap of code which you have presented, so it's hard to tell the purpose of it.

```
mov     ebx, 0ffff0000h**       ;Why are we writing mov ebx, 0ffff0000h here? 
add     ebx, eax                ;further I understand 
neg     ebx
```

This is unusual way how to load `EBX` with absolute value from `AX`. (I would use `MOVSX EBX,AX`). If the result of addition in `AX` is negative (-5), it jumps to `Sign_Flag:` with undefined garbage in the upper half of `EAX`. Let's assume that it was cleared before the addition, then `EAX=0000_FFFBh`, add it to `EBX=0FFFF_0000h` and now you have `EBX=0FFFF_FFFBh`, which is **-5**. After `NEG EBX` it gives `EBX=0000_0005h` which will be (together with minus sign in DL) sent on output via `On_ASCII`.

Comment: Are you assuming that the high 16 bits of EAX are zero?  This code in the question does nothing to ensure that, to make sure the add is equivalent to `mov bx, ax`.  But yeah, this looks like manually tacking on the sign-extension for a negative number, and then negating (in a block that runs only if AX was negative).  (So yeah, `movsx ebx, ax` / `neg ebx`.  MOVSX alone wouldn't be equivalent to this 3-instruction block)